# Compare dictionary keys with array to extract matching and non matching data

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to retrieve Facebook friends list and display the user if he is following another users or not. For that I am using FacebookID's stored on parse backend and when the user clicks on Follow button, I add his FacebookId to the key value "following" in parse. Later I retrieve this following key array and display the user that the currentUser is following or not following.

My friend list:

```
var friend = ["902165525": "John", "10204125099": "Sam", "153822": "Sandy", "475585616": "Nito"]
```

I am following:

```
var follow = ["10204125099", "153822"]
```

Now I want to extract the `friend` array where I can see the friends that I am "not following" i.e the `else` block.

```
wantToGetThis -> ["902165525": "John", "475585616": "Nito"]
```

What I have is,

```
    func check() {

    for all in self.follow {

        for (key, value) in friend {

            if key.containsString(all) {

                print("Yes: \(key), \(value)")

            } else {
                print("No: \(key), \(value)")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I get for `if` loop

```
Yes: 10204125099, Sam

Yes: 153822, Sandy
```

This is what I get for `else` loop

```
No: 153822, Sandy

No: 902165525, John

No: 475585616, Nito

No: 902165525, John

No: 10204125099, Sam

No: 475585616, Nito
```

Why am I getting Sandy and Sam in `else` block and multiple John and Nito? What is wrong in here?

Comment: Did you try to *debug* your code? Set a breakpoint and single-step? At what point does the execution not follow the path that you expect?

Comment: Usually you check if a set (friend) contains a subset (follow) rather than the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not print anything in the inner loop. Instead you should use it to see if any item matches the current one from the outer loop, and print the result after the loop is over:

```
for (key, value) in friend {
    var found = false
    for all in self.follow {
        if key == all {
            found = true
            break
        }
    }
    if found {
        print("Yes: \(key), \(value)")
    } else {
        print("No: \(key), \(value)")
    }
}
```

Note that the order of the loops should be changed as well: the inner loop should become outer, so that you retain access to `key` and `value` after the inner loop is over.

Comment: I am sorry, but if I don't use the inner loop, how would I get access to "key" and "value" ?

Comment: @Riding.Driving You need to flip your loops around, with the outer loop going inside.

Comment: I just did that right after posting you. It worked. I have one question though, which one is more efficient as the array size increase? The one with for loop I requested in this question or the one @vadian posted above using filter?

Answer (score 1):

Swift's `filter` function can be applied to dictionaries, the key / value pairs are treated as tuples.

```
let peopleIFollow = friend.filter{ follow.contains($0.0) }
let peopleIDontFollow = friend.filter{ !follow.contains($0.0) }
for person in peopleIFollow {
  print("I follow \(person.0) \(person.1)")
}
for person in peopleIDontFollow {
  print("I don't follow \(person.0) \(person.1)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I now have two options, one from you and other from @dasblinkenligh below. Which one do you think will be more efficient as the array size increase?

Comment: I don't know. In this case with 2 separate filter operations the loop seems to be the more efficient solution. You could figure it out in a playground: Create a huge array and measure both options by time stamps.